# Maclaurin Series

Tags: integration

> Integrate using first three terms of appropriate series...
>   $$\int_0^1 \sin x ~dx.$$

So I use
$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$$
for my three terms and if I integrate *just* that I get the answer which is $.3103$.

However the solution book is showing a negative is taken outside the integral then just sorta disappears.

Am I missing something here or is this a typo? (What follows is what is in the book):

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\sin x^2\,dx &= \int_0^1\left(x^2 - \frac{(x^2)^3}{3!} + \frac{(x^2)^5}{5!}\right)\,dx\\
&= -\int_0^1\left(x^2 - \frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{x^{10}}{120}\right)\,dx\\
&= \left.\left(\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{x^7}{42} + \frac{x^{11}}{1320}\right)\right|_0^1\\
&= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{42} + \frac{1}{1320} = 0.3103.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Definitely a typo.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. And I'm not wild about them claiming the first integral is **equal** to the second (it's **not**, it's just an approximation) or that $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{42}+\frac{1}{1320}$ is exactly equal to $0.3103$ (again, that's just an approximation). What book is this?

Comment: Basic Technical Mathematics with Calculus 9th ed. Allyn J. Washington

Comment: How did you manage to edit my question to use the symbols?

Comment: @ChefFlambe: I typed out your image using LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the minus sign is a typo and should not be there.

Note as well that you don't actually have equalities. Since
$$\sin x\approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!},$$
and we don't have actual equality, we have that
$$\int_0^1\sin(x^2)\,dx \approx \int_0^1\left(x^2 - \frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{x^{10}}{120}\right)\,dx.$$
Likewise, in the final line we actually have
$$\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{42} + \frac{1}{1320}\approx 0.3103,$$
not equality.